# What is the Chasam Sofer saying here about תש"פ being bad and תשפ"א being good?

Tags: jewish-books, chatam-sofer

He seems to be saying something about תש"פ being bad and תשפ"א being good.

[image: Screenshot of page in question here]

Comment: One interesting point re gematria is that תש"פ is equivalent to תשעה באב,  and תשפ"א is תשועה.

Comment: He's not talking about the years at all

Comment: @wfb i did get that. So what is the context here? (If you noticed, my question did not mention the word "year".)

Answer (score 3):

He doesn't say that תשפ"א is good - he says that its gematria value is the ultimate low - the garbage dump!

Then based on the verse "from the dumps He elevates the destitute" he infers that the next step has to be a major improvement.

Comment: Do you know what the context here is about these gematria's? Why is he talking about this stuff here?

Comment: What does he say about תשפ?