# Chasam Sofer on Parshas Bechukosai

Tags: sources-mekorot, chatam-sofer

I looked up the Chasam Sofer with the piece that is boxed and could not find it.

[image]

Is there anyone who is well-versed in his writings that provide me with a link to his sefer?

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking. You want to know where to find Chasam Sofer Al HaTorah p. 185? Or you want this particular piece on p. 86

Comment: The particular piece on p. 86.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what it's talking about? I asked a question about it here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117131/9431

Answer (score 7):

This is a piece from **Chasam Sofer Al HaTorah** published by [**Rav Yosef Stern**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%9F), the **Chasam Sofer**'s grandson's son-in-law, in 1961 (not to be confused with **Toras Moshe**, published by [**Rav Shimon Sofer**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8_(1850)), the **Chasam Sofer**'s grandson, in 1879). Since it was published too recently, this is probably why it isn't available on Hebrewbooks.org, and probably why you couldn't find it.

However, it is available on [Otzar HaChochmah](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=53195&pagenum=117). The first 150 pages on Otzar HaChochmah are free for viewing, so luckily for you it's accessible.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you appreciate the answer you can upvote and accept it as correct.